# Tkinter: Adding and self-deleting buttons in list | Adding works, Deleting not

Tags: python, button, tkinter, callback, optionmenu

I am just in the middle of creating an entry form for a program, and it seems that I have got stuck with the logic on this one.

Basically I wanted to design a dropdwon-list, which adds words to an array and displays these words as little buttons beneath it. When you click the buttons they disappear again and remove themselfs from the array.
Simple enough, I thought. The adding worked fine so far. But removing not so much... There is a logic error with the button array and I can't seem to figure it out!

I extracted the code for reviewing,

any help is greatly appreciated!

[Word adding Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlH0G.png)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def rel_add(*args):
    rel_array.append(tkvar.get())
    print(rel_array)
    rel_buttons_update()


def del_button(i):
    print(i)
    del rel_array[i] 
    print(rel_array)
    rel_buttons[i].grid_remove()
    # del rel_buttons[i]
    rel_buttons_update()


def rel_buttons_update():
    for i, rel in enumerate(rel_array):
        rel_buttons.append(tk.Button(rel_grid, text=rel, font="Helvetica 7", command=lambda c=i: del_button(c)))
        rel_buttons[i].grid(column=i, row=0, sticky="nw")

rel_array = []
rel_buttons = []
win = tk.Tk()                           

tkvar = tk.StringVar(win)             # Create a Tkinter variable

choices_words = ["oolbath", "pflanze", "haus", "wasser", "brimbambum"]      # Create Variable List

tkvar.set('Related Words...')              # set the default option
choices_words.sort()                        # Sort List

tk.Label(win, text="Related Words: ").grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="w")
rel = tk.OptionMenu(win, tkvar, *choices_words)   
rel.grid(row=0,column=1, sticky="w")  

# Callbuck Function for Dropdwon Menu

tkvar.trace("w", rel_add)

rel_grid = tk.Frame(win)



# Display the Buttons for the related Words

rel_grid.grid(row=1,column=1, sticky="w") 


win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you keep recreating the same buttons over and over, so `rel_buttons` contains many more elements than you expect.

As a simple experiement, add a print statement to `rel_buttons_update` like this:

```
def rel_buttons_update():
    for i, rel in enumerate(rel_array):
        rel_buttons.append(ttk.Button(rel_grid, text=rel, command=lambda c=i: del_button(c)))
        rel_buttons[i].grid(column=i, row=0, sticky="nw")
    print('in update, rel_buttons is now', rel_buttons)
```

You'll notice that there is one button the first time you use the option menu, three buttons the second time, six buttons the third time, and so on.

You need to either only create new buttons, or delete all the old buttons before recreating them.

Comment: Ok thanks for that!  But the problem for me is not that I don't know that I have to delete the buttons; the problem would be that I can't figure out _ where _  to do that. After some tries, I came up with something like this:
 
` def rel_buttons_update(arr):

    for rel in rel_buttons:
        rel.destroy()
        
    rel_buttons = [] `

in the update_function, but it keeps getting messier!

Comment: Or in other words: The problem is, that the lambda command references not this specific button, with which it is created - so the del_button function doesn't delete anything most of the time.

Comment: @fschober: yeah, that's another way of putting it. You're using an index into an array, and you're not properly managing the array so the index refers to a different widget than you think it does.